# Multiple layouts for the Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

Can I choose different layout for the Fragment  based on the Button that has been clicked on the Activity, or should I create one Fragment class for each Button?

I know that Fragments exist to accommodate different UI but in my case I have many buttons that on click display a FrameLayout  and  I was thinking if it is possible to save time from copy/paste ?

Comment: create one Fragment class for each Button is the solution. "I know that Fragments exist to accommodate different UI but in my case I have many buttons that on click display a FrameLayout and I was thinking if it is possible to save time from copy/paste?" Could you be a bit more specific?

Comment: I thought so! :(  Thank you blackbelt

Answer (score 1):

I'd say that depends on how your layouts/fragments look like. If they are huge and very similar it could be better to have one layout. You could also think about using `<merge />` or `<include/>` in that case.

This way you can maintain equal parts in (sub-)layouts without the need of code repetition.

Have a look at Googles site [here](http://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/reusing-layouts.html).

Comment: They aren't huge. I'll stick to the copy/paste approach. Thanx for the link.

Comment: In that case I agree with _blackbelt_ (unless you need hundreds of layouts).